# QML in blackberry Native SDK 10.0

Tags: c++, qml, blackberry-10

In following QML code

```
  Container {
            horizontalAlignment: HorizontalAlignment.Fill
            verticalAlignment: VerticalAlignment.Top

            topPadding: 100
            leftPadding: 30
            rightPadding: 30
}
```

Properties:values pairs can be identified. From where do the values(HorizontalAlignment.Fill etc;) come from. Is it QML,c++ or some other language?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking, can you rephrase the question?

Answer (score 0):

HorizontalAlignment is an enum type in C++. The header file has been compiled int a moc file (which is C++) then compiled and linked into the library that the qml compiler uses. So it comes ultimately from C++ but is available in QML and JavaScript (under QML).